# Optimizing SQL Stored Procedure Query for better performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization

Is there a way to optimize the query below as its took quite awhile to retrieve the massive records from the table (T_School_Class) and (T_School)  I had created indexes for Name as well as SchoolCode for T_School. In additional, Temp Table was also created.

```
        SELECT Distinct (S.SchoolCode) As Code, Name from T_STU_School AS S
        LEFT JOIN T_STU_School_Class AS SC ON S.SchoolCode = SC.SchoolCode
        WHERE S.SchoolCode  IN
        (SELECT SchoolCode FROM @MainLevelCodeTemp)
        AND [Status] = 'A' 
        AND Name LIKE @Keyword
        AND (@AcademicCode = '' OR SC.AcademicLevel IN (@AcademicCode))
        Order BY Name ASC;
```

Comment: What database are you using? Where is the query plan?

Comment: MSSQL, The query is plan to retrieve all the records out base on the user search 'Keyword', but if the user does not enter any 'Keywords'. It will display all the records in the database.

Comment: @Stella I think what he meant by query plan is `query execution plan` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan .. using this tool, we can find which part of the query gives the biggest cost

Comment: @samAlvin hey thanks so much, i had posted the execution plan already. =)

Comment: We need the table definitions and the index definitions.  Also, how many rows are returned and how long does it take?  Finally, how much faster do you need it to be?

Comment: Does `@Keyword` has wildcards at start and end ? Qualify the column names to suggest index

Comment: Can you post the relevant tables DDL + some sample data as DML? also, desired output would help a lot. Why did you choose to work with table variables? Can you post the entire procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the imperatives in the sproc are a waste, you're just forcing SQL to scan T_STU_School multiple times, all that logic should just be added to the where clause:

```
SELECT Distinct (S.SchoolCode) As Code, Name from T_STU_School AS S
LEFT JOIN T_STU_School_Class AS SC ON S.SchoolCode = SC.SchoolCode
WHERE ((@MainLevelCode LIKE '%J%' AND S.MixLevelType IN ('T1','T2','T6'))
   OR  (@MainLevelCode LIKE '%S%' AND S.MixLevelType IN ('T1','T2','T5','T6'))
   OR  (@MainLevelCode LIKE '%P%' AND S.MixLevelType IN ('T1','T2','T6'))
   OR  (MainLevelCode IN (SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[SplitString](@MainLevelCode, ',')))
   OR  @MainLevelCode = '')
AND [Status] = 'A' 
AND (@Keyword = '' OR Name LIKE @Keyword)
AND (@AcademicCode = '' OR SC.AcademicLevel IN (@AcademicCode))
Order BY Name ASC;
```

..the reason both tables are still being scanned per your execution plan even though you've created indexes on `Name` and `SchoolCode` is because there's no criteria on `SchoolCode` that would reduce the result set to less than the whole table, and likewise with `Name` whenever it is blank or starts with a "%". to prevent the full table scans you should create indexes on:

```
T_STU_School (Status, Name)
T_STU_School_Class (MixLevelType, SchoolCode)
T_STU_School_Class (MainLevelCode, SchoolCode)
```

..also any time you have stuff like `(y='' OR x=y)` in the where clause it's a good idea to add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the bottom to avoid the eventual bad plan cache nightmare.

..also this line is probably a bug:

```
AND (@AcademicCode = '' OR SC.AcademicLevel IN (@AcademicCode))
```

`IN` won't parse `@AcademicCode` so this statement is equivalent to `SC.AcademicLevel=@AcademicCode`

Comment: Thanks gordy, but when i tried to modify the logic into 1. this particular sentence fails. OR  (MainLevelCode IN [dbo].[SplitString](@MainLevelCode, ','))

Comment: @Stella it should be `OR (MainLevelCode IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.SplitString(@MainLevelCode, ',')))`

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need an index on `T_STU_SCHOOL.SchoolCode`. Your query plan shows that 65% of the query time is taken from the index scan that results from the join. An index on the `SchoolCode` column should turn that into an index seek, which will be much faster.

The `Name` index is not currently being used, probably because you're passing in values for `@keyword` that start with a wildcard. Given that Name is on the T_STU_School table, which has a small number rows, you can maybe afford a table scan there in order to use wildcards the way you want to. So you should be able to drop the Name index.